# Webview not plays video

Tags: android, kotlin, video, webview

I have a function:

```
private fun WebView.initVideo(video: String) {
    WebViewVideoPlayerUtils.addCookie(video, this)
    with(settings) {
        javaScriptEnabled = true
        domStorageEnabled = true
        cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE
        builtInZoomControls = true
        allowFileAccess = true
        loadWithOverviewMode = true
        useWideViewPort = true
    }
    loadDataWithBaseURL(
        null,
        video,
        "text/html",
        "utf-8",
        null
    )
}
```

And it worked fine. But after updating project it's not playing video. Just shows String

`<iframe width=“853” height=“480” src=“https://www.youtube.com/embed/_iATsZKqYF0" frameborder=“0” allow=“accelerometer;autoplay;encrypted-media;gyroscope;picture-in-picture” allowfullscreen></iframe>`

[image]

How could I Fix it?

P.S. AndroidManifest.xml contains needed permission and

android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

P.P.S: Using logs I find out that parameter video comes as a String:

```
&lt;iframe width=&quot;853&quot; height=&quot;480&quot; src=&quot;https://www.youtube.com/embed/_iATsZKqYF0&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot; allow=&quot;accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture&quot; allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
```

And it works fine if I manually change it to

```
"<iframe width=\"853\" height=\"480\" src=\"" + "https://www.youtube.com/embed/_iATsZKqYF0" + "\" frameborder=\"0\" allow=\"accelerometer;autoplay;encrypted-media;gyroscope;picture-in-picture\" allowfullscreen/>"
```

As if Android can't parse it
I have a lot of screens using this strings for playing video. So how could I resolve this problem in one place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just the encoding mistake on the server side.
Adding the line

```
val parsedVideo = Html.fromHtml(video, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY).toString()
```

resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed end quotes in `src`. Please replace with this :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <title>Online HTML Editor</title>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <iframe width="853" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_iATsZKqYF0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer;autoplay;encrypted-media;gyroscope;picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're right, but it was typo only in my problem explanation (already edited). Actually that String contains all quotes

Comment: @Helios i think the issue is in your quote. You can copy above code snippet with quotes and check.

Comment: No, unfortunately there is everything ok with quotes

Comment: @Helios add this lines in your AndroidManifest.xml and check : `<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true">` and `<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254437/discussion-between-helios-and-kedar).